# How do I make a Carousel with 4 slides on Desktop only display one slide on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, mobile-website

How do I make a Carousel with 4 slides switch to one slide and arrows when displayed on a mobile device?

My carousel has been created using HTML, CSS, JS

This is the HTML code:

```
                       <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                <!-- First image from slider -->
                                                    <img src="assets/images/iv.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/dm.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/b.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/cc.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/dc.jpg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/da.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/ptd.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="port_item xs-m-top-30">
                                                <div class="port_img">
                                                    <img src="assets/images/dro.jpeg" alt="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>

                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
```

The above code is basically displaying images. One `listbox` display 4 images. When the user clicks the `Next` arrow it slides to the next slide and displays another 4 images.

How do I change it so when the `max-width` is triggered for a mobile display, the carousel becomes responsive and only displays 1 slide over the 4 slides.

For the moment my `@media (max-width: 400px)` doesn't hold anything within it.
Through the use of the class names provided within the HTML, can you help me write a few lines to fix my issue for mobile devices.

I have also added a few images for reference. 
- [Desktop Carousel Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTOK2.png)
- [Mobile Carousel Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i25A.png)

Comment: can you please make working snippet of it?

Comment: Can you reference the website I can use to do that?

Comment: You can try this https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I was hoping to get it done with what I already have in place

Comment: so please add full code..to help you